# Cannot ssh to a localhost port other than 22 on MacOS

Tags: macos, ssh

I am trying to use X11 forward from the server of my university to my PC. I have to ssh to a jump server then ssh to the dest server. Since it worked well on my Windows device with XShell and XManager using a tunnel, I tried to do so on my Mac with `ssh -Nf -L 8964:xx.xx.xx.xx:22 user@yy.yy.yy.yy`. Then when I tried to use command `ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 8964 -v` in another terminal window as I did on Windows, It shown that

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/Lighter/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 8964.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:8964 as 'Lighter'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:efxiadogxOHYAx2SinQT6v2fqIpGQxuZeAP7LNx/l7g
debug1: Host '[127.0.0.1]:8964' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Lighter/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:NuR1ClQtXikP9fVFaJ4X1duTxN5M3XpC6/ihuZrd8wA
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:BEGqSHGs5ctncTbVzSnthaXr19Awt4XQKVpltCf//Ok
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:NuR1ClQtXikP9fVFaJ4X1duTxN5M3XpC6/ihuZrd8wA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:BEGqSHGs5ctncTbVzSnthaXr19Awt4XQKVpltCf//Ok
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Lighter/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
Lighter@127.0.0.1's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
Lighter@127.0.0.1's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
Lighter@127.0.0.1's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Lighter@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Before that I tried to generate key using `ssh-genkey` and it worked so I can connect to port 22 without password. But though I entered the password correctly here, It just kept showing permission denied. I searched the whole Internet but no right answer.

Here is my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Port 22
Port 8964
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
PermitTunnel yes
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# pass locale information
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

# XAuthLocation added by XQuartz (http://xquartz.macosforge.org)
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my question that though using ssh to connect to localhost, remote username must be used to login to remote server. So this command is the right one:

```
ssh remoteuser@127.0.0.1 -p 8964
```